# Program works on computers with VS 2012 but not without

Tags: wpf, xaml

Just a weird issue, I have made a WPF xaml program and when i test it, it works, I publish it and it works.  but if i install the published app or run the debug folder on a computer without VS installed I get the following error:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: program.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 51cade56
  Problem Signature 04: MJ_QAQC
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 51cade56
  Problem Signature 07: 294
  Problem Signature 08: 1c
  Problem Signature 09: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParse
  OS Version:   6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I don't know if this means anything to anyone, but I am suspecting that it has to do with the xaml.  are there any other prerequisites other than .net 4.5 that need to be installed in order to run a xaml app?

thanks!

Comment: You *may* want to debug this using the [Fusion log viewer.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)  Just make sure to run it as admin, turn on the log, and reboot before attempting to debug.  You'll see where the CLR is looking for any missing assemblies, and what version, and from there determine why it isn't being found (if you even have it installed).

Comment: I have updated the question with the error log

Answer (score 2):

> are there any other prerequisites other than .net 4.5 that need to be installed in order to run a xaml app?

It depends.  You'll need to also deploy any other assemblies your application uses which aren't part of the core framework.

If you use a 3rd party control, for example, you'd need to include that control in your deployment.  Checking the project references for non-framework assemblies should allow you to find these dependencies.

Comment: as an experiment I changed all of my application files to include, still nothing.  How do I go about deploying references?  thanks!

Comment: I just find it wierd that having VS installed make the difference.

Comment: @Herrozerro Are you sure you're deploying the *release* build, and not the debug build?

Comment: I zipped the release folder with the setup and moved it to a VM without VS installed and ran the setup, it crashes after installation and anytime i try to run it.

Comment: I have updated the question with the error log from fusion viewer

Comment: 1. Compile the wpf app. 2. Move the release folder to the other machine. It should be working there without an installator (I assume the app is rather simple). 
3. The log shows you forgot to copy resource files

Comment: @swiszcz  I have done so, same issue.  After looking at the release folder vs the error, i am not seeing and /en-US/ folder in my release like it is saying it is looking for.  Is there some kind of localization issue?

Comment: @Herrozerro What locale is the other system?  Is it the same as yours? (ie: are both US systems?)

Comment: Did you try to create a WPF Hello World application, and to move it on the other system?

Comment: So i have done a few more tests since yesterday.  I ran fusion viewer on the VM with VS that works, that same issue is happening with that resource.dll but its running, so I dont think that's actually an issue.

I wan a quick hello world app on the VM its not working on and it worked, so it seems like it is something in the app giving me a Xaml parse error.

Comment: Is there a good way to dump the output to a log file?  This is quite the connumdrum.  I cant debug it in VS because it works if VS is installed, but I dont know how to debug without a debugger.

Comment: @Herrozerro Add a try/catch around the InitializeComponent call in the constructor,a nd print out the exception (wtih the inner exception details, as that's where the "real" problem tends to lie)

Comment: Around the initial window's initialize?  I put a try catch around that with a messagebox to display any errors, it still fails.

Comment: @Herrozerro Could even be App.xaml.cs that needs it, depending on what you're loading...

Comment: so should i put all the text in app.xaml.cs in a try block?

Comment: @Herrozerro You could try it - it's really figuring out where your exception is occurring that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5` for your other machines, do you have `Microsoft.CSharp.dll` or `System.Xaml.dll`? Some of your machines may have them already, which is why some of them can run it, and some can't.

Note: It may not be under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5`, could be under a different directory in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\.`

When you do a publish, it adds those libraries that you wouldn't need when you are running Visual Studio since you already have them in the `Reference Assemblies` directory.

Comment: I am actually not seeing a v4.5, just v4.0 on my windows 7 machine.

Comment: @Herrozerro it should work just the same, it is whatever version you have latest. 4.5 is `v4.0.30319.17929` and 4.0 is `v4.0.30319.1`, if you wanted to know.

Comment: So comparing the two different VMs, the one with VS has the 4.5 folder, and the one without does not.  when i published the app I included 4.5 as a prerequisite to install, and I installed it.  I even redownloaded it and repaired it.  Shouldn't it be in that folder?

Comment: the VN with VS also has several different folders, such as .net core